# Exoplyaer won't return current position from service to activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I have `Exoplayer` in my `service` class. I want to send `exoplayer` current position from `service` to `activity`. I have created a `broadcast receiver` for communication. Here is my code for broadcast receiver inside my activity class

```
class LocalAudioPlayer : AppCompatActivity() { 

inner class LocalAudioReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            Log.i("here","here34")
            intent?.getStringExtra("message")?.let { Log.i("heythere", it) }
        }

    }



override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        registerReceiver()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        unregisterReceiver(localAudioReceiver)
        super.onStop()
    }

    private fun registerReceiver() {
        localAudioReceiver = LocalAudioReceiver()
        val intentFilter = IntentFilter()
        intentFilter.addAction(SENDMESAGGE)
        registerReceiver(localAudioReceiver, intentFilter)
    } ..
```

Following are the ways in which I tried to send back data from service to activity

First way
I wrote following code in `onStartCommand` of service

p

```
layer?.addListener(object : Player.EventListener {
            override fun onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady: Boolean, playbackState: Int) {
                when (playbackState) {
                    Player.STATE_ENDED -> {
                        //                    showControls();
                        //                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playback ended", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    Player.STATE_BUFFERING -> {
                        Log.i("heyyy","nnnnn")
                        passMessageToActivity(player?.currentPosition.toString())
                        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                            Log.i("hey123", "here123")
                            passMessageToActivity(player?.currentPosition.toString())
                        }, 0)
                        //                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Buffering..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    Player.STATE_READY -> {
                        //                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                    Player.STATE_IDLE -> {

                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

Second way I tried moving the above code from `onStartCommand` to `onCreate` but it does not work

Third Way

Tried adding the above code in onCreate but it does not work

```
 Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
        Log.i("hey123","here123")
        passMessageToActivity(player?.currentPosition.toString())
    }, 0)
```

Fourth way

```
Runnable {
            passMessageToActivity(player?.currentPosition.toString())
        }
```

I am returning null in `onBind` of service. Is that causing issue?
I want to continuously send exoplayer current position from service to activity

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking a way communicate with `Activity` from `Service` class, make use of `LocalBroadcastManager`.

Inside `Activity`, create a broadcast receiver and register

```
private val playerStateChangedReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if (intent?.action == "player_state_changed") {
            val currentPosition = intent.getIntExtra("current_position", 0)
            toast("Current position: $currentPosition")
        }
    }
}

 override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context)
        .registerReceiver(playerStateChangedReceiver, IntentFilter("player_state_changed"))
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context)
        .unregisterReceiver(playerStateChangedReceiver)
}
```

From `Service` do this to send broadcast

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context)
                .sendBroadcast(Intent("player_state_changed").apply {
                    putExtra("current_position", adapterPosition)
                })
```